# iOS certificated on developer account and their role in App building

Tags: ios, xcode, xcode9, apple-developer

I have been an android developer and was thinking the life is not easy but then I found the iOS developer account and its relativity with project creation and other certifications.

I have developed the app, then in that App, I need to add FCM notifications. For this, I have installed FCM pod. And made necessary changes in the project.

Now its turn for me to connect my project with FCM ios ( and ios APNS with FCM server)

So good so far. Now I want to create a different team for this project. But When I create a distribution certificate it always creates a file with the name of the team I was using before i.e ABCD.  I tried to create another profile but it just creates ABCD named file.

Can anyone tell what could be the problem?

2nd what are the steps required to create a production certificate for FCM to launch the app in the store?

Please discuss the first point in detail why it is happening? Why I can't change the name of the certificate.

Note: Whenever I try to create a development certificate it take another name

Please let me know what is going on..........

Answer (score 0):

Xcode generates certificate fully automatic these days. You should let it automatically build them for you till you experienced more with apple signing process.

you can change any identifiers you want **before** sending any kind of build to appStore, (for example for test flight)

If you didn't upload to appstore yet, you can just login with your other account in Xcode and choose it from the team dropdown in signing section of general tap in Xcode. Then Xcode tries to sign the app with new credentials.

For FCM, follow the original [documentation of FCM](https://firebase.google.com/docs/cloud-messaging/ios/certs?authuser=2).

And at the end, Welcome to iOS world ;)

Comment: thanks. But can you share me link on certificates and also on FCM procedure on how to create fcm certificates and all that bad things :)

Comment: I linked my answer to `Configuring APNs with FCM` documentation.